# Why can't I adjust proportional size?

Tags: vertices

[image]
I am new to blender and am trying to grab only a part of the mesh and move it with the sphere tool for the falloff. I read that you press g and scroll up and down to make the scope bigger/smaller so you don't move the entire mesh, but when I do that, a dotted yellow line and square appear instead and the whole mesh starts rapidly moving around.

[image]

I would really appreciate some help on this, it's driving me insane!

Comment: you are using the edge slide tool in the bottom picture (`G`  `G` is the shortcut). simply turn on proportional editing, then move your selection like you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select proportional editing first(at the bottom the 3d view), then hit g to grab.

[image]